# What are the basic linguistic characteristics of the Maltese language?

Tags: reference-request, semitic-languages

I've been looking for a website or something helpful for my presentation about the Maltese language and I didn't find something that offers good explanation of the Phonological, morphological, syntactic, etc... characteristics of the Maltese language. Anything helpful?

Comment: There are grammars and teaching materials for the Maltese language, go to your university library to check them out (they are printed on paper, I'm afraid).

Comment: How basic is "basic"? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_language) has a sketch of many of these areas, together with a reference list.

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want Maltese, you should check the references given [here](https://glottolog.org/resource/languoid/id/malt1254). In general, for *any* language, a good starting point is to check that same site, Glottolog, for materials that they know of. It's the best language-bibliographic site on the market.